# Didn't find service registered by hostname after 60 seconds - Openstack/devstack deployment fails

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

While trying to deploy Openstack environment on a single machine, I am using devstack to achieve it. While running the stack.sh script to deploy the setup. Its failing.

```
+::                                        ID=
+::                                        [[ '' == '' ]]
+::                                        sleep 1
+::                                        [[ libvirt = \f\a\k\e ]]
++::                                        openstack --os-cloud devstack-admin --os-region RegionOne compute service list --host chypserver --service nova-compute -c ID -f value
+functions:wait_for_compute:450            rval=124
+functions:wait_for_compute:462            time_stop wait_for_service
+functions-common:time_stop:2336           local name
+functions-common:time_stop:2337           local end_time
+functions-common:time_stop:2338           local elapsed_time
+functions-common:time_stop:2339           local total
+functions-common:time_stop:2340           local start_time
+functions-common:time_stop:2342           name=wait_for_service
+functions-common:time_stop:2343           start_time=1567866711847
+functions-common:time_stop:2345           [[ -z 1567866711847 ]]
++functions-common:time_stop:2348           date +%s%3N
+functions-common:time_stop:2348           end_time=1567866772092
+functions-common:time_stop:2349           elapsed_time=60245
+functions-common:time_stop:2350           total=80867
+functions-common:time_stop:2352           _TIME_START[$name]=
+functions-common:time_stop:2353           _TIME_TOTAL[$name]=141112
+functions:wait_for_compute:464            [[ 124 != 0 ]]
+functions:wait_for_compute:465            echo 'Didn'\''t find service registered by hostname after 60 seconds'
Didn't find service registered by hostname after 60 seconds
+functions:wait_for_compute:466            openstack --os-cloud devstack-admin --os-region RegionOne compute service list
+----+----------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID | Binary         | Host       | Zone     | Status  | State | Updated At                 |
+----+----------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
|  9 | nova-scheduler | chypserver | internal | enabled | up    | 2019-09-07T14:32:44.000000 |
| 16 | nova-conductor | chypserver | internal | enabled | up    | 2019-09-07T14:32:47.000000 |
|  1 | nova-conductor | chypserver | internal | enabled | up    | 2019-09-07T14:32:47.000000 |
+----+----------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
+functions:wait_for_compute:468            return 124
+lib/nova:is_nova_ready:1                  exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:533                  local r=124
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:534                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:534                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:537                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:543                  '[' -f /tmp/tmp.pyeCyALAPA ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:544                  rm /tmp/tmp.pyeCyALAPA
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:548                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:443               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:550                  [[ 124 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:551                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:553                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:554                  generate-subunit 1567864383 2390 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:556                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
```

I expect it pass over this step and deploy the Openstack environment.

Answer (score 0):

Is the hostname chypserver resolvable? Try adding it to your local hosts (`/etc/hosts`) file.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost    chypserver
```

Comment: I did updated the hosts file but it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get ID of the **nova-compute** service, which is clearly not available. Please, check the table. Only nova-conductor and nova-scheduler are running. Investigate the nova-compute service on the chypserver machine (*systemctl status devstack@n-cpu**, *journalctl -xe -u devstack@n-cpu**, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Just run the same command from command prompt

openstack --os-cloud devstack-admin --os-region RegionOne compute service list --host chypserver --service nova-compute -c ID -f value

which will solve the problem.

Comment: While running this command am having an infinit block in the terminal, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I unintendedly messed up with the KVM/QEMU configuration which in my case is `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64` and `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu`.

So all I need to do is reverting changes I done earlier, run `systemctl reload apparmor`, and reboot.

In your case, the problem might be similar -- related to the hypervisor -- although the exact problem could be slightly different. So try to check if your hypervisor (KVM, QEMU, etc) is running properly.